# How to extract the name of a column from a data frame to be used in the loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, names, tapply

I would like to copy the text of a data frame's column names one-by-one in a for loop. My code seems to return NULL values from the column name argument.

More broadly, I want to create a summary by factor of each of several columns.

```
# Create an example data frame
df <- data.frame( c( "a", "b", "c", "b", "c"), c( 6, 4, 10, 9, 11), c( 1, 3, 5, 3, 6))

colnames(df) <- c( "Group", "Num.Hats", "Num.Balls")
```

[image: example data frame with each group member's number of hats and number of balls]

Now I want to loop over columns two and three, creating a data object storing the summary statistics by Group. The point is to get a look at how groups A, B, and C differ from one another with respect to balls and with respect to hats.

My code looks like this:

```
# Evaluate stats of each group
for (i in 2:3){
    assign(paste0("Eval.", colnames(df[[i]])), tapply(df[,i], df$Group, summary))
}
```

I am getting a single object called `"Eval."` With the summary statistics for `Num.Balls`. To be clear, I would like two objects, one called `Eval.Num.Hats` and one called `Eval.Num.Balls`.

If `colnames()` cannot be used in this way, is there another function to achieve my desired result? Alternatively, I'd be open to another solution if the loop is not required.

Comment: You can do `colnames(df)[i]`

Comment: I think you are looking at doing groupby summarize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `df[[i]]` is extracting the column as a `vector` and there are no `colnames`.  We can either use `df[i]` or the correct option is `colnames(df)[i]`

```
for (i in 2:3){
    assign(paste0("Eval.", colnames(df)[i]), tapply(df[,i], df$Group, summary))
 }
```

-output

```
Eval.Num.Hats
#$a
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#      6       6       6       6       6       6 

#$b
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   4.00    5.25    6.50    6.50    7.75    9.00 

#$c
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#  10.00   10.25   10.50   10.50   10.75   11.00 

Eval.Num.Balls
#$a
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#      1       1       1       1       1       1 

#$b
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#      3       3       3       3       3       3 

#$c
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   5.00    5.25    5.50    5.50    5.75    6.00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid a for-loop altogether.

***Explanation:***

Here, using `lapply` I am looping over all columns (using their names) to be summarized, except the first one which is used for grouping (see what `names(df1)[-1]` returns).

`with` function basically attaches the dataframe so you don't need to do `dataframe$column` and you can simply type the column name.

`by(variable to function, grouping variable, function)` is used to apply `summary` by group.

We need to use the column name as variable and not character. That's why I am using `mget()` to convert the character name of the column to the variable.

```
smry.ls.df1 <- lapply(names(df1)[-1], function(col) with(df1, by(mget(col), Group, summary)))
names(smry.ls.df1) <- paste0("Eval.", names(df1)[-1]) #setting the names as you've shown
```

```
smry.list.df1

#> $Eval.Num.Hats
#> Group: a
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>       6       6       6       6       6       6 
#> -------------------------------------------------------- 
#> Group: b
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>    4.00    5.25    6.50    6.50    7.75    9.00 
#> -------------------------------------------------------- 
#> Group: c
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   10.00   10.25   10.50   10.50   10.75   11.00 
#> 
#> $Eval.Num.Balls
#> Group: a
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>       1       1       1       1       1       1 
#> -------------------------------------------------------- 
#> Group: b
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>       3       3       3       3       3       3 
#> -------------------------------------------------------- 
#> Group: c
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>    5.00    5.25    5.50    5.50    5.75    6.00
```

If you want them to be saved as separate objects (not recommended) you can use `list2env`:

```
list2env(smry.list.df1, globalenv())
```

***Data:***

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Group = c( "a", "b", "c", "b", "c"), 
                  Num.Hats = c( 6, 4, 10, 9, 11), 
                  Num.Balls = c( 1, 3, 5, 3, 6))
```

Comment: Very helpful. Can you explain what function(col) does? Also, does col in mget(col) function as a sort of nonspecific, universal placeholder for data frame columns?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution without any loops, using `tidyr` and `broom`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

df %>%
  #Change from wide to long format
  pivot_longer(cols = c("Num.Hats","Num.Balls"),
               names_to = "Var") %>%
  #group by Group (a,b,c) and Var (Num.Hats, Num.Balls)
  group_by(Group, Var) %>%
  #Calculate the summary function for each group
  do(tidy(summary(.$value)))

# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   Group, Var [6]
#  Group Var    minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum
#  <fct> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 a     Num.B~       1  1       1     1    1          1
#2 a     Num.H~       6  6       6     6    6          6
#3 b     Num.B~       3  3       3     3    3          3
#4 b     Num.H~       4  5.25    6.5   6.5  7.75       9
#5 c     Num.B~       5  5.25    5.5   5.5  5.75       6
#6 c     Num.H~      10 10.2    10.5  10.5 10.8       11
```

Comment: I really like how clean this code is. It makes sense to me to transpose the column names as variables. However, I am getting the following error:
install.packages("tidy")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tidy’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed an "r" at the end of `tidyr`. I already corrected the error on the post. It should work now.